# Running node app without node_modules folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, github

My professor wants us to submit our project for our node.js app but we are not allowed to include node_modules in the submission.

When I try to run the app without the folder in there, it crashes due to missing dependencies.

Am i missing a step?

Comment: Why not ask your professor what the reason for the restriction is, so you understand the scope of what you're being asked to do? How are strangers on the internet likely to guess at a better answer than your professor can give you directly?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably either

- you're not supposed to use third-party dependencies in your solution (just the core Node.js modules), or
- you're not supposed to include `node_modules` in your submission (which is good practice anyway), but instead just have a `package.json` (and possibly a lockfile) so your instructor can `npm i` / `yarn` to install the packages.

Comment: Hope the edit is okay. If not, please rollback. :-)

Answer (score 0):

When building an app that has node_modules you aren't supposed to include this anyway.

Install any node_modules that are required for your application to run and when sibmitting just leave out the node_modules folder.

Your package file will include everything that your instructor can check over or install on their end if necessary.

I found this random example on github: https://github.com/hayanisaid/nextjs-intro-example

As you can see by looking they have there package files but no node_modules, when you clone this repo you would run npm install which would create and install the packages

Answer (score -1):

package.json contains information about node modeuless.

If u deleted node modules, you just have to run npm i --save.
All the dependency will be downloaded through this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).